# How to get the value of ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-contacts

I am trying to insert contacts programatically in Xamarin.Android.

I have found this Java code and was trying to convert it to Xamarin C#

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(); ops.add(ContentProviderOperation .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI) .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null) .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null) .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED).build());
```

Usually the difference with the constants of RawContacts is that in Xamarin C#, constants were using pascal casing. The ACCOUNT_TYPE and ACCOUNT_NAME were inside RawContacts.InterfaceConsts.

But I cannot seem to find the ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED in Xamarin.Android. I did discover from the Java Android documentation that its value is 3 but I don't want to hard code it. So where to find the value of ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED in Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me

```
Android.Provider.AggregationMode.Disabled
```